# How do I handle an error despite the code is in a try block

Tags: python-3.x, exception, pandas-groupby

I put my block of code that I know is generating the error in a `try` block but I still keep getting a KeyError `error`. I know the reason for getting this error is that sometimes the dataframe is empty

```
try:
    df = df.groupby(by='col1')['col2'].agg(total = 'sum').reset_index()
except KeyError:
    raise Exception from None
```

Why am I still getting an error message when I have already put my code in a `try` block. How do I get around this?

Comment: Probably because the handler block just raised another exception...??

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
except KeyError:
    raise Exception from None
```

to:

```
except KeyError as e:
    print(e)
```

See what happens. Problem could be you have an exception within an exception.

Comment: @wim - My initial understanding what on the same line as yours, but unfortunately it wasn't that. @rzaratx It was a weird error that `pandas` was throwing. I broke down my code into multiple code blocks (without any change to the code) and then error was resolved just fine.